# How to use a gazebo plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have written a simple gazebo world plugin and compiled it (following the tutorial).
Now I am not sure how to use this plugin. I am using ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.0.4.
Is there a tutorial to explain it? Can I simply add a plugin tag into the .world file?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40510/how-to-use-a-gazebo-plugin/) by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i think this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials/plugins/simple_world) may help you

---

Originally posted by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) with karma: 234 on 2012-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zara](https://answers.ros.org/users/2831/zara/) on 2012-08-13**:
I thought this tutorial can be used for standalone gazebo not gazebo with ROS. Am I right?

**Comment by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on 2012-08-14**:
yes this is for standalone gazebo....but the part of using a plugin can be used for both standalone and for  gazebo with ros.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2017-06-06**:
Please update the link as it is dead.